# Windows Batch Loop Recursively to find all files with given name

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm trying my best at writing a windows batch.
I want to list all files with given name "ivy.xml" in a directory and all its subdirectories.
Example:

- Releases

  - Program01

    - 1.0.0

      - ivy.xml
    - 2.0.0

      - ivy.xml
  - Program02

    - 1.0.0

      - ivy.xml
    - 2.0.0

      - ivy.xml

So the output should be:

- "Releases/Program01/1.0.0/ivy.xml"
- "Releases/Program01/2.0.0/ivy.xml"
- "Releases/Program02/1.0.0/ivy.xml"
- "Releases/Program02/2.0.0/ivy.xml"

Code:

```
for /R "Releases" %%f in (ivy.xml) do echo "%%f"
```

But what I get is this:

- "Releases\ivy.xml"
- "Releases\Program02\ivy.xml"
- "Releases\Program02\1.0.0\ivy.xml"
- "Releases\Program02\2.0.0\ivy.xml"
- "Releases\Program01\ivy.xml"
- "Releases\Program01\1.0.0\ivy.xml"
- "Releases\Program01\2.0.0\ivy.xml"

Comment: Why not just use `DIR /S /B IVY.XML`?

Comment: I think that `ivy.xml` needs to include a wildcard, which could be a simple case of adding a `?` or a `*`, but unless you are certain that those will not match other unwanted files too, I'd advise that you use `where.exe` with its `/R` option, or the `dir` command with its `/S` option  in a `For /F` loop instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `for /R` loop just iterates through the whole directory tree when there is no wildcard (`?`, `*`) to match against, so extend it by `if exist` to return existing items only:

```cmd
for /R "Releases" %%f in (ivy.xml) do if exist "%%f" echo "%%f"
```

If there might be sub-directories called `ivy.xml` too you could exclude them by this:

```cmd
for /R "Releases" %%f in (ivy.xml) do if exist "%%f" if not exist "%%f\*" echo "%%f"
```

Given that there is no file matching the pattern `ivy.xml?`, you could also just do this:

```cmd
for /R "Releases" %%f in (ivy.xml?) do echo "%%f"
```

Another option is the `dir` command, given that there is no directory called `ivy.xml` in the root directory `Releases`, whose contents would then become returned instead:

```cmd
dir /S /B /A:-D "Releases\ivy.xml"
```

Yet another option is to use the `where` command (the `PATHEXT` variable is cleared in the current session in order not to return files like `ivy.xml.exe`, for instance):

```cmd
set "PATHEXT="
where /R "Releases" "ivy.xml"
```